# What does lag function in R do?

Tags: r, time-series

I am debugging R code and I am pretty much confused about how `lag` function in R works. For example

```
> x=c(0)
> x
[1] 0
> lag(x)
[1] 0
attr(,"tsp")
[1] 0 0 1
```

Another example

```
> x=c(0,0,0,1)
> x
[1] 0 0 0 1
> lag(x)
[1] 0 0 0 1
attr(,"tsp")
[1] 0 3 1
```

Can someone explain me what exactly `lag` function does in plain english.

I am specifically concerned about how the return values are computed.

Keep in mind this question is from a programmer trying to learn R rather than a statistician.

Comment: have you read `?lag`? what's unclear?

Comment: "Compute a lagged version of a time series, shifting the time base back by a given number of observations." . . I thought stackoverflow is meant to clarify things rather than pointing to docs

Comment: It is meant to clarify things, but how are we supposed to know what you're confused about when you're so vague? "I'm confused about how this function works" and "What does this function do?" are not very specific. Be explicit about what isn't clear or doesn't make sense and people will be more likely to help you.

Comment: Can anyone explain how the return values are computed / point to concrete example rather than pointing to theoretical pile of documentation.

Comment: > lag
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("lag")
<bytecode: 0x47e4810>
<environment: namespace:stats>

I dont see a 12 line function here.

Comment: People ask questions when they are not able to figure out things by themselves. If anyone wants to answer, please answer or let others do rather than justifying that the question should not be asked.

Comment: @Anoop, sorry, I had `dplyr` loaded, which has a 12-line implementation.

Comment: Yes, people ask questions when they aren't able to figure things out themselves, but you haven't demonstrated that you've tried anything. There's an example in the documentation, and [searching for `[r] lag`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+lag) yields some very helpful results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**plain vectors** `lag` is a generic which means it can act differently on objects of different classes.  Here we will only discuss how it works with a plain vector but in the last two sections we will also discuss `"ts"`, `"zoo"` (and `"zooreg"`) class objects and how they are lagged.  As an example, we use this vector of values:

```
x <- c(11, 12, 13, 14)
```

**tsp** Realize that a time series is a sequence of times and the values at those times. Here we only have the values but not the times so `lag` conceptually adds regularly spaced default times of 1, 2, 3, 4 by adding a `tsp` attribute which is a triple that encodes the start time, the end time and the frequency (i.e. the reciprocal of the distance between successive times).  We can encode the times 1, 2, 3, 4 as the `tsp` attribute c(1, 4, 1).  1 is the start time.  4 is the end time.  The time points are all 1 apart (because the time differences 2-1, 3-2 and 4-3 each equal 1) and 1/1 = 1 so the frequency is 1.  A quarterly series whose times are measured in years would have a frequency of 4 since each successive quarter would be 0.25 apart and 1/0.25 = 4.  Similary, a monthly series measured in years would have a frequency of 12.

**lag** `lag` shifts the times one back. It does not change the values, only the times.  Thus lag changes the `tsp` attribute from `c(1, 4, 1)` to `c(0, 3, 1)`.  The start time is shifted from 1 to 0, the end time is shifted from 4 to 3 and since shifts do not change the frequency the frequency remains 1.

```
> lag(x)
[1] 11 12 13 14
attr(,"tsp")
[1] 0 3 1
```

**time** The `time` function will produce an object whose values are the times of its argument and whose `tsp` attribute is the same as the `tsp` attribute of its argument (or the default `tsp` attribute if none).  For example, as we already discussed the code below shows that the times of the plain vector `x` given above are 1, 2, 3, 4 and the times for `lag(x)` are 0, 1, 2, 3.

```
> time(x)
[1] 1 2 3 4
attr(,"tsp")
[1] 1 4 1
> time(lag(x))
[1] 0 1 2 3
attr(,"tsp")
[1] 0 3 1
```

**ts**  Most operations on plain vectors ignore the `tsp` attribute so unless you do something with it its existence may be pointless.  On the other hand, if the object were a `"ts"` class object then the various operations on `"ts"` objects do pay attention to the `tsp` attribute.  For example, note where these plots start:

```
# plain vector
plot(x) # plot starts at time = 1
plot(lag(x)) # same, tsp was ignored

# ts object
plot(ts(x)) # plot starts at time = 1
plot(lag(ts(x))) # plot starts at time = 0, tsp was not ignored
```

**zoo** The series above was regularly spaced, i.e. the differences between successive times were the same.  To represent irregularly spaced series one can use the `"zoo"` and `"zooreg"` classes in the zoo package.  A zoo object is the values with an `index` attribute holding the times.   The times are not encoded in a `tsp` attribute.  For example, here we see that the zoo objects has times 1, 2, 3, 4 held and values 11, 12, 13, 14:

```
> library(zoo)
>
> str(zoo(x))
‘zoo’ series from 1 to 4
  Data: num [1:4] 11 12 13 14
  Index:  int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
```

The `"zooreg"` class is like `"zoo"` for objects which are regularly spaced except for some times that may be omitted.  Internally `"zooreg"` objects are the same as `"zoo"` objects except the frequency is also stored.  The values and index are the same as for zoo but we know have a frequency as well.  Since the successive time points are 1 apart the frequency is 1.

```
> str(zooreg(x))
‘zooreg’ series from 1 to 4
  Data: num [1:4] 11 12 13 14
  Index:  num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  Frequency: 1
```

If one lag a `"zoo"` object then each time is moved to the prior time and the first time dropped.  Here the times are 1, 2, 3 and the values are 12, 13, 14.  Note that the lagged series has a subset of the times of the original series.  That is always the case when lagging a zoo series:

```
> lag(zoo(x))
 1  2  3 
12 13 14
```

Because `"zooreg"` objects have a frequency they can be lagged to times that did not exist in the original series.  Each time point t is lagged to t - deltat where deltat is 1/frequency.  Here 0, 1, 2, 3 are the lagged time points and the values are 11, 12, 13, 14:

```
> lag(zooreg(x))
 0  1  2  3 
11 12 13 14
```

**dplyr** The dplyr package has a `lag` function.  Unfortunately it acts in the opposite direction of the base R `lag` function in that `lag(x, k)` moves each item in the series forward rather than backwards.  This may actually be more intuitive but causes a lot of confusion due to the incompatibility with base R.  If you use dplyr be very careful that you know whether dplyr is loaded or not.

dplyr's `lag` is particularly useful when used with data frames since given a vector (such as a column of a data frame) it always returns a vector of the same length.  It has a `default=` argument which itself defaults to NA but can be specified by the user to determine what the empty value(s) at the beginning of the vector are to be filled in with.  Negative lags are not allowed but the dplyr `lead` function can be used.

```
dplyr::lag(1:5)
## [1] NA  1  2  3  4

dplyr::lag(1:5, 2)
## [1] NA NA  1  2  3

dplyr::lead(1:5)
## [1]  2  3  4  5 NA
```

Answer (score 11):

`lag` takes an atomic vector and returns that same vector with an added attribute of three numbers indicating the start, end, and frequency of a lag of length one on the vector you supplied. Vectors in R are indexed from 1, so the start value for a lag of length one is 0 and, in your case, the end is 3 (one short of the length of the vector). Finally, frequency specifies how many elements should be attributed to each index.

#### Example (courtesy of @GavinSimpson)

```
x <- ts(c(0,0,0,1))
x
lag(x)

> x
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 4 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 0 0 0 1
> lag(x)
Time Series:
Start = 0 
End = 3 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 0 0 0 1
```

Note how the vector (`[1] 0 0 0 1`) is unchanged but the **Start** and **End** properties of the time series *are* modified as one would expect for a lag. For this to be of use, you need a function that understands R's `ts` objects. If using something else, you may need to lag the vector yourself.

Comment: You're describing the `tsp` attribute of the returned object, not the returned object itself.

Comment: The area that confused the heck out of me for several years and made me never want to use R ts objects again was the fact that lag doesn't really change the vector, but rather changes the time base. That's not what I expected.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier for the OP to understand what is going on if you make `x` from their example a `ts` object to compare with the one that lag creates. Then it is clear that the vector is unchanged and just the time unit *t* to which each observation is linked is modified?